# How to create static pages that are translatable?

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

How to create Drupal 8 static pages that are translatable (3-lingual site)?

I already have HTML code and about 15 static pages which some have dynamic content (latest news etc).

What's the best approach in Drupal? 
Do I create lots of blocks with my html or something else?

Comment: I tried to explain myself better without editing previos question

Comment: Editing existing questions is allowed, even encouraged :) We're not just asking/answering questions here.. we're building a repository of good questions and answers that others can benefit from as well.